# Angular and Type script support Plugin for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I looked for angular and typescript plugin for intellij.

However couldn't find a good plugin.

Does any suggest a good intellij plugin for angular and typescript support?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't like their official plugin ? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/angular.html

IMO just don't use IntelliJ, so many unnecessary features light a fire in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is supported out of the box; for Angular support, please try [Angular and AngularJS](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angular-and-angularjs) plugin. Note that TypeScript/Angular support require IDEA Ultimate, there are no plugins for Community Edition

Comment: Is because of the complexity, no opensource plugin doesn't exist?

Comment: there are no opensource plugins for that; and yes, this is a complex functionality that depends on web technologies support that is missing in CE